# docker-compose can't get into new container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm using docker-compose to create a new image and a container as well, but after I ran `docker-compose up -d`, I cannot get into the container with this: `docker-compose exec -it container_name (name specified in docker-compose)`.

What is working is that I can login to a new container if I do: docker-compose run netcore, which is my service-name, (please see my docker-compose.yml below and Dockerfile if needed), and I can see the share volume and so for.

I tried this in the container (the one defined with "container_name": `docker run -it --rm container_name`, I can't either login.

Of course, the container appears as running when I do: `docker ps -as`.

I do end up with 2 containers, the one creates during `docker-compose up -d`, that I cannot get into, and the one created when I ran the service called "netcore".

Must be easy, but I can't work this around.

Can someone advice what I'm missing? thanks.

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  netcore:
    container_name: test_alerting_comp
    image: alerting_netcore
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "c:/FakePath/git/my_project/src:/app"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app
```

```
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "src_net" with the default driver
Creating test_alerting_comp ... done
docker exec -it test_alerting_comp /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container ae23ff9075bc200a78fe8e7a21d65476b4ccf19c2b239263e54c7dd278ce37ea is not running
docker ps -as
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES                SIZE
ae23ff9075bc        alerting_netcore    "bash"              44 seconds ago      Exited (0) 42 seconds ago                          test_alerting_comp   0B (virtual 1.74GB)
```

Comment: Try just `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`

Comment: Hi @Nordle,I did it before, I have added the full output to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output of `docker ps -a` it says that your container is exited with status code `0`, so it is not running and you cannot get into it.

You are starting your container detached but without a terminal attached, so the container stops after directly after it is startet. You need to add the options `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true` to your compose file

Comment: FYI passing the `-t` switch to the docker run command auto assigns a tty.

Comment: Hi @Jack, Certainly you were, I didn't spot the code `Exited (0)`. I have added those two options to my `docker-compose` file and it is working totally fine, Highly appreciate :-)